# Redux Reducer how to update normalized state children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have payload A which represents a n-deep nested tree which looks like.. (You can think of sections array as children on a tree)

```
const data = {
  id: 123,
  sections: [{
    id: 1,
    sections:[{ id: 4, sections: [ { id: 5, sections: [] } ] }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    sections:[]
  }, {
    id: 3,
    sections:[]
  }]
};
```

The normalized state of payload A looks like following

```
    {
  "entities": {
    "sections": {
      "1": { "id": 1, "sections": [ 4 ] },
      "2": { "id": 2, "sections": [] }, 
      "3": { "id": 3, "sections": [] },
      "4": { "id": 4, "sections": [ 5 ] },
      "5": { "id": 5, "sections": [] }
    },
    "menu": {
      "123": { "id": 123, "sections": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
    }
  },
  "result": 123
}
```

If the user was to expand the section 5 I would go off and load more children from the server. The payload B returned from server when normalized would look like

```
{
  "entities": {
    "sections": {
      “6”: { "id": 6, "sections": [] }, 
    },
    "menu": {
      "1234”: { "id": 1234, "sections": [ 6 ] }
    }
  },
  "result": 1234
}
```

How do I write a reducer to combine(merge/map etc) normalized payload A and normalized payload B so the new Redux store state looks like the following...

```
    {
  "entities": {
    "sections": {
      "1": { "id": 1, "sections": [ 4 ] },
      "2": { "id": 2, "sections": [] }, 
      "3": { "id": 3, "sections": [] },
      "4": { "id": 4, "sections": [ 5 ] },
      "5": { "id": 5, "sections": [6] },
    “6”: { "id": 6, "sections": [] }
    },
    "menu": {
      "123": { "id": 123, "sections": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
    }
  },
  "result": 123
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be hard to achieve, in your reducer I am sure you are maintaining the previous state, pull out the values from previous state `entities.sections` in the following fashion

`var newData = {...state.entities.sections,newSectionPayload}`

`newSectionPayload` should contain the data for newly expanded section.

I haven't tried it but I'm pretty sure it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my reducer to solve the above and it seems to do the trick

```
export const productHierarchyReducer: ActionReducer<ProductHierarchyState> = (state:any={}, action: Action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PRODUCTHIERARCHY:
             const normalizedTreeNodes = normalize(action.payload, TreeNodesSchema);          
             return normalizedTreeNodes; 
         case ADD_PRODUCTHIERARCHY_CHILDREN:

                   const {targetNodeId, payload} = action.payload;
                   const normalizedChildNodes = normalize(payload, TreeNodesSchema);   

                   const expandTargetNode=dotProp.set(
                        state, 
                         `entities.children.${targetNodeId}.expanded`, 
                            expanded => true
                        );

                     const updatedWithNewChildren = dotProp.set(
                        expandTargetNode, 
                         `entities.children.${targetNodeId}.children`, 
                            children => 
                            children.concat(normalizedChildNodes.entities.nodes[normalizedChildNodes.result].children)
                        );

                     const newState=dotProp.set(updatedWithNewChildren, 
                         `entities.children`,
                           children =>  Object.assign({}, children, normalizedChildNodes.entities.children) 
                         )   

                   return newState;

        default:
            return state;
    }    
};
export const ProductHierarchyReducer = {
    productHierarchy: productHierarchyReducer
}
```

Also the TreeNodesSchema looks the following.

```
const nodeKey = new schema.Entity('children')
const children = new schema.Array(nodeKey);
nodeKey.define({ children });
export const TreeNodesSchema = new schema.Entity('nodes', { children });
```

The dotProp.set() syntax belongs to dot-prop-immutable 
https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable

This resource on updating Normalized state was useful
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html